# TCPDF and FPDI, footer with page nr. not working

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdi

I'm using TCPDF in combination with FPDI. All working good except the Footer (want to add Page Numbers there).

My Code:

```
    // Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends FPDI {

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 5, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}

// add external PDF with FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', true);

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(1, 4, 1, 1, true);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 3);
```

... this footer hook is working fine if I'm not suing FPDI. What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

You are initiating an instance of `FPDI` and not of `MYPDF`. For sure the `Footer()` method will not be invoked that way.

IIRC you also have to leave `setPrintFooter()` to true.

Comment: Doesn't really help. As soon I'm using FPDI I can't extend the class for the footer?

Comment: But that's exactly what I tell you: Initiate `MYPDF` and not `FPDI`.

Comment: yes, but if I initiate MYPDF I can't use any FPDI function anymore. (to include existing pdf files).

Comment: Sorry, but then you're doing something wrong, which is out of my scope. I told you what's wrong with the code in your question.